# D3 tween does not work inside angular

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm working on this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

I wrapped this into a directive. For some reason, the tween method does not get fired.

```
    var transition = d3.transition()
    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
    .tween("zoom", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
      return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
    });
```

Is tween incompatible with angular ? Any idea where I should start looking ?

Comment: Did you try to name tween differently? Also try naming your transition d3.transition('somename').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small fiddle from the above http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535.

I have incorporated the d3 svg component via directive and the tween works perfectly.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {"name":"flare","children":[{"name":"analytics","children":[{"name":"cluster","children":[{"name":"AgglomerativeCluster","size":3938},{"name":"CommunityStructure","size":3812},{"name":"HierarchicalCluster","size":6714},{"name":"MergeEdge","size":743}]},{"name":"graph","children":[{"name":"BetweennessCentrality","size":3534},{"name":"LinkDistance","size":5731},{"name":"MaxFlowMinCut","size":7840},{"name":"ShortestPaths","size":5914},{"name":"SpanningTree","size":3416}]},{"name":"optimization","children":[{"name":"AspectRatioBanker","size":7074}]}]},{"name":"animate","children":[{"name":"Easing","size":17010},{"name":"FunctionSequence","size":5842},{"name":"interpolate","children":[{"name":"ArrayInterpolator","size":1983},{"name":"ColorInterpolator","size":2047},{"name":"DateInterpolator","size":1375},{"name":"Interpolator","size":8746},{"name":"MatrixInterpolator","size":2202},{"name":"NumberInterpolator","size":1382},{"name":"ObjectInterpolator","size":1629},{"name":"PointInterpolator","size":1675},{"name":"RectangleInterpolator","size":2042}]},{"name":"ISchedulable","size":1041},{"name":"Parallel","size":5176},{"name":"Pause","size":449},{"name":"Scheduler","size":5593},{"name":"Sequence","size":5534},{"name":"Transition","size":9201},{"name":"Transitioner","size":19975},{"name":"TransitionEvent","size":1116},{"name":"Tween","size":6006}]},{"name":"data","children":[{"name":"converters","children":[{"name":"Converters","size":721},{"name":"DelimitedTextConverter","size":4294},{"name":"GraphMLConverter","size":9800},{"name":"IDataConverter","size":1314},{"name":"JSONConverter","size":2220}]},{"name":"DataField","size":1759},{"name":"DataSchema","size":2165},{"name":"DataSet","size":586},{"name":"DataSource","size":3331},{"name":"DataTable","size":772},{"name":"DataUtil","size":3322}]},{"name":"display","children":[{"name":"DirtySprite","size":8833},{"name":"LineSprite","size":1732},{"name":"RectSprite","size":3623},{"name":"TextSprite","size":10066}]},{"name":"flex","children":[{"name":"FlareVis","size":4116}]},{"name":"physics","children":[{"name":"DragForce","size":1082},{"name":"GravityForce","size":1336},{"name":"IForce","size":319},{"name":"NBodyForce","size":10498},{"name":"Particle","size":2822},{"name":"Simulation","size":9983},{"name":"Spring","size":2213},{"name":"SpringForce","size":1681}]},{"name":"query","children":[{"name":"AggregateExpression","size":1616},{"name":"And","size":1027},{"name":"Arithmetic","size":3891},{"name":"Average","size":891},{"name":"BinaryExpression","size":2893},{"name":"Comparison","size":5103},{"name":"CompositeExpression","size":3677},{"name":"Count","size":781},{"name":"DateUtil","size":4141},{"name":"Distinct","size":933},{"name":"Expression","size":5130},{"name":"ExpressionIterator","size":3617},{"name":"Fn","size":3240},{"name":"If","size":2732},{"name":"IsA","size":2039},{"name":"Literal","size":1214},{"name":"Match","size":3748},{"name":"Maximum","size":843},{"name":"methods","children":[{"name":"add","size":593},{"name":"and","size":330},{"name":"average","size":287},{"name":"count","size":277},{"name":"distinct","size":292},{"name":"div","size":595},{"name":"eq","size":594},{"name":"fn","size":460},{"name":"gt","size":603},{"name":"gte","size":625},{"name":"iff","size":748},{"name":"isa","size":461},{"name":"lt","size":597},{"name":"lte","size":619},{"name":"max","size":283},{"name":"min","size":283},{"name":"mod","size":591},{"name":"mul","size":603},{"name":"neq","size":599},{"name":"not","size":386},{"name":"or","size":323},{"name":"orderby","size":307},{"name":"range","size":772},{"name":"select","size":296},{"name":"stddev","size":363},{"name":"sub","size":600},{"name":"sum","size":280},{"name":"update","size":307},{"name":"variance","size":335},{"name":"where","size":299},{"name":"xor","size":354},{"name":"_","size":264}]},{"name":"Minimum","size":843},{"name":"Not","size":1554},{"name":"Or","size":970},{"name":"Query","size":13896},{"name":"Range","size":1594},{"name":"StringUtil","size":4130},{"name":"Sum","size":791},{"name":"Variable","size":1124},{"name":"Variance","size":1876},{"name":"Xor","size":1101}]},{"name":"scale","children":[{"name":"IScaleMap","size":2105},{"name":"LinearScale","size":1316},{"name":"LogScale","size":3151},{"name":"OrdinalScale","size":3770},{"name":"QuantileScale","size":2435},{"name":"QuantitativeScale","size":4839},{"name":"RootScale","size":1756},{"name":"Scale","size":4268},{"name":"ScaleType","size":1821},{"name":"TimeScale","size":5833}]},{"name":"util","children":[{"name":"Arrays","size":8258},{"name":"Colors","size":10001},{"name":"Dates","size":8217},{"name":"Displays","size":12555},{"name":"Filter","size":2324},{"name":"Geometry","size":10993},{"name":"heap","children":[{"name":"FibonacciHeap","size":9354},{"name":"HeapNode","size":1233}]},{"name":"IEvaluable","size":335},{"name":"IPredicate","size":383},{"name":"IValueProxy","size":874},{"name":"math","children":[{"name":"DenseMatrix","size":3165},{"name":"IMatrix","size":2815},{"name":"SparseMatrix","size":3366}]},{"name":"Maths","size":17705},{"name":"Orientation","size":1486},{"name":"palette","children":[{"name":"ColorPalette","size":6367},{"name":"Palette","size":1229},{"name":"ShapePalette","size":2059},{"name":"SizePalette","size":2291}]},{"name":"Property","size":5559},{"name":"Shapes","size":19118},{"name":"Sort","size":6887},{"name":"Stats","size":6557},{"name":"Strings","size":22026}]}]}
}]);
app.directive('packChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var root = scope.myData;
            var margin = 20,
                diameter = 960;

            var color = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([-1, 5])
                .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
                .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

            var pack = d3.layout.pack()
                .padding(2)
                .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
                .value(function (d) {
                return d.size;
            })

            var svg = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("width", diameter)
                .attr("height", diameter)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");
            var focus = root,
                nodes = pack.nodes(root),
                view;

            var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) {
                return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
            })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;
            })
                .on("click", function (d) {
                if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
            });

            var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
                return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
            })
                .style("display", function (d) {
                return d.parent === root ? null : "none";
            })
                .text(function (d) {
                return d.name;
            });

            var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

            d3.select("body")
                .style("background", color(-1))
                .on("click", function () {
                zoom(root);
            });

            zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

            function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus;
                focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", function (d) {
                    var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
                    return function (t) {
                        zoomTo(i(t));
                    };
                });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                    .filter(function (d) {
                    return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline";
                })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
                    return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0;
                })
                    .each("start", function (d) {
                    if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline";
                })
                    .each("end", function (d) {
                    if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none";
                });
            }

            function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = diameter / v[2];
                view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
                });
                circle.attr("r", function (d) {
                    return d.r * k;
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node:hover {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node--leaf {
    fill: white;
}
.label {
    font: 11px"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}
.label, .node--root, .node--leaf {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
     <h1>My Chart</h1>

    <svg pack-chart></svg>
</div>
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4tohdqm4/1/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem was datejs. Once I removed it, D3 transitions work fine.